# Adding breakouts for external components in Eagle PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I have an external actuator which is connected to a component on the PCB board. This connection will be through wiring.

However, I cant seem to find the breakout component which will allow me to solder wires onto the PCB. Does anyone know how to do this on eagle PCB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an appropriate connector footprint - you don't need to install the connector.

Or you could make a suitable footprint yourself - it probably just needs a few pads with holes of a convenient size to solder the wires.  You would also want an appropriate schematic component to go with the footprint.

If you do any amount of PCB design, you *will* have to make your own PCB footprints and schematic components.

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently looking for pads to solder wires too.  That is about as easy as it gets to make your own.  It would have been quicker to just do it than ask here.  If you don't know how to make your own parts in Eagle, then you need to stop and learn that before proceeding.  First, it's really not hard.  Second, it is useful, even necessary, to know this.

If you install my Eagle Tools release from http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm, you will get a bunch of Eagle libraries.  See the PAD-xxx devices in the CONNECTOR library as examples.  These include a number of thru-hole pads of various diameters.  These are what I use for external wires that will be connected by soldering.